# How to shift/move multiple rows from the top of the dataframe to the bottom and then replace the shifted rows with new dates

Tags: python

this is a script I've been working on for a while - it's been slow and steady progress. Whenever I get the time I would try and add new things but it seems like I've been stuck in a continual loop of coding new things and new errors popping up which wastes more time.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, timedelta
from datetime import datetime 

#path to Excel spreadsheet
names = ['date', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]
df = pd.read_excel(Test.xlsx', header=None, names=names)

#a = current start date
a = df['date'].min()

#input new start date 
b = input("Enter start date as dd-mm-YYYY")
b = datetime.strptime(b, "%d-%m-%Y")

#converting datetime to timedelta
b1 = timedelta(hours=b.hour, minutes=b.minute, seconds=b.second)

#output a + b as the day of week 
b2 = b.weekday()
a2 = a.weekday()

#the difference in days between start date and new start date
#defining c (new start date - current start date)
c = (b2 - a2)
print(c)

#shift to bottom
def shift_row_to_bottom(df, index_to_shift):
    idx = [i for i in df.index if i!=index_to_shift]
    return df.loc[idx+[index_to_shift]]

#change range(2) to range([index)])...  somehow
for i in range(5): df = shift_row_to_bottom(df, c)

#changing column date to represent the values
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('D').dt.start_time + pd.Timedelta((c), unit='d')
print(df)
```

Actual Output >>>>

```
Enter start date as dd-mm-YYYY04-04-2019
3

           date  1  2  3  4  5  6    7    8         9  ...        39 
0    2019-04-04  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.133881   
1    2019-04-05  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.134704   
2    2019-04-06  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.135519   
4    2019-04-08  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.137126   
5    2019-04-09  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.137917    
1092 2022-03-31  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
1093 2022-04-01  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
1094 2022-04-02  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
1095 2022-04-03  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
3    2019-04-07  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.136326   

            40        41        42        43  44  45  46  47  48  
0     0.052225  0.019840  0.002768  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0  
1     0.052546  0.019961  0.002785  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0  
2     0.052864  0.020082  0.002802  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0  
4     0.053491  0.020320  0.002835  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0  
5     0.053799  0.020438  0.002852  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0   
1092  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
1093  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
1094  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
1095  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
3     0.053179  0.020202  0.002819  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0
```

As the title says, I would like to shift multiple rows from the top of the dataframe (along with the data) to the bottom and then replace the shifted rows (under the column 'date' column) with new dates - so for instance, the moved row would be replaced by 2022-04-04. So far, I've only managed to shift one row but using C. I can't find any solutions online so I've come to you guys for help - please let me know if you would like any more information!

Edit: so I have essentially shifted the top 4 rows to the bottom of the dataframe and then amended the dates so they continued.

Expected Output >>>

```
Enter start date as dd-mm-YYYY04-04-2019
3

           date  1  2  3  4  5  6    7    8         9  ...        39    
4    2019-04-08  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.137126   
5    2019-04-09  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.137917    
1092 2022-03-31  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
1093 2022-04-01  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
1094 2022-04-02  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
1095 2022-04-03  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  ...  0.000002   
1096 2022-04-04  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.133881   
1097 2022-04-05  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.134704   
1098 2022-04-06  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.135519
1099 2022-04-07  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.000009  ...  0.136326   

            40        41        42        43  44  45  46  47  48   
4     0.053491  0.020320  0.002835  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0  
5     0.053799  0.020438  0.002852  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0   
1092  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
1093  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
1094  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
1095  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0   0   0   0   0  
1096  0.052225  0.019840  0.002768  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0  
1097  0.052546  0.019961  0.002785  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0  
1098  0.052864  0.020082  0.002802  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0 
1099  0.053179  0.020202  0.002819  0.000004   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: can you elaborate by writing `'expected output'` and `'actual output'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shift/move multiple rows from the top of the dataframe to the bottom, one can use the `concat` as one of a few methods (for example  you can use the `.iloc[]` and `.loc[]` to select the rows and reorder the dataframe).

An example with `concat` looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'B': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

# Get the first 3 rows
top_rows = df.head(3)

# Get the remaining rows
bottom_rows = df.tail(-3)

# Concatenate the top_rows and bottom_rows to create a new DataFrame
new_df = pd.concat([bottom_rows, top_rows])

# Display the new DataFrame
print(new_df)
```

The result from the example look like this:

```
   A   B
3  4  40
4  5  50
0  1  10
1  2  20
2  3  30
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you use the iloc method?

Comment: @Oatnuj,  you can see how `iloc` works from here:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html,  but in the case of the question, `head` and `tail` is cleaner - because this is what the question primariy requested.

Comment: that worked like a charm - much appreciated! With regards to my second query, how would I ensure the dates are consecutive from 1095?

Comment: @Oatnuj, in your code, to sort by date, you would do this:  `df = df.sort_values(by='date')`.